# Spring MVC + Ajax JSON post

Tags: java, json, ajax, spring, spring-mvc

I have a problem with send `JSON` to the `Controller`. I can't understand my problem.

So, url - `/notes/{username}/add`

**Ajax**:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType : 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType : 'json',
        url: window.location.pathname,
        data: JSON.stringify({ title: $("#title").val(), text: $("#text").val() }),
        success : function() {
            $("#title").val("");
            $("#text").val("");
        }
    });
```

**Controller**:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{username}/add", method = POST)
    public void add(@RequestBody Note note) {
        noteRepository.add(new Note(UserSession.getUser(), note.getTitle(), note.getText()));
    }
```

**Note**:

```
public class Note {

    private String title;
    private String text;

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }
}
```

Controller don't get request from ajax. I think, problem with url, but I can't why and what to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your `controller` as:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "{username}/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void add(@RequestBody Note note, @PathVariable("username")String username) {
}
```

And your ajax call url should include the path variable as:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType : 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType : 'json',
        url : '/Notes/notes/username/add',
        data: JSON.stringify({ title: $("#title").val(), text: $("#text").val() }),
        success : function() {
            $("#title").val("");
            $("#text").val("");
        }
    });
```

Also make sure your `pom.xml` or `build.gradle` should have jackson dependency, below is an example for maven project:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.13</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not helps to me

Comment: What is the `applicationcontext` name of your `app`?

Comment: Change `url` in ajax call as `url : '/Notes/notes/username/add',`

Comment: Again did not help, may I give you link to the git?

Comment: your app is able to build but causing error at time of deployment, anyways I created a sample which solves your problem - https://github.com/arpitaggarwal/spring-mvc-ajax, hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you, Arpit, for your help!!!
I managed to solve the problem, in part. The problem was in the host arguments.

I tried to do 'RequestBody String title'
And ajax data is $("#title").val();
And it turned out to take data to the controller!

But when I do 'RequestBody NoteModel note'
And ajax data are title and text values.
Then, unable to receive data.

Why?
It is NoteModel - http://pastebin.com/Zg9fVMSX
And I have libraries - jackson-databind, jackson-mapper-asl

And, I have question. When data turned out, ajax don't do success. Why?

Comment: Hope this link help you - https://gerrydevstory.com/2013/08/14/posting-json-to-spring-mvc-controller/

Comment: Thanks, but it's not help to me.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating data like this

```
data: JSON.stringify({ title: $("#title").val(), text: $("#text").val() }),
```

you can try seralize your html form like this

```
<form name-"yourformname" id="formname">
<input type="text" id="title" name=="title"/>
<input type = "text" id="text" name="text"/>
</form>
<input type="button" value="Submit"/>
```

In Ajax do this

```
    $.ajax({
            var formdata = $('#yourformname').serializeArray();
            type: "POST",
            contentType : 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType : 'json',
            url : '/Notes/notes/username/add',
            data: formdata,
            success : function() {
                $("#title").val("");
                $("#text").val("");
            }
        }
```

);

**Model**

```
public class Note {

    private String title;
    private String text;

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/{username}/add", method = POST)
@ResponseBody
        public void add(Note note) { //In note instance you will get the json data
            //your code 
        }
```